# How can I make TS-Node to use type definitions from `vite-env.d.ts`?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, vite, chai, ts-node

I'm running Mocha/Chai among TS-Node to unit test the functionality of a React/TypeScript app built with Vite.

By now tests run as expected, except for the ones that need to consume type definitions from `vite-env.d.ts`. The problem is that I'm struggling to reference those types to be used by TypeScript when parsing through TS-Node.

Folder structure:

```
myProject/
  src/
    ts/
      myModule.ts
    vite-env.d.ts
  test/
    unit/
      myModule.spec.ts
    .mocharc.json
    tsconfig.json
package.json
```

Configuration files:

```json
// package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --config test/.mocharc.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

```json
// test/.mocharc.json
{
  "loader": "ts-node/esm",
  "extensions": [
    "ts"
  ],
  "spec": [
    "test/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "watch-files": [
    "src/vite-env.d.ts",
    "src/ts/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "experimental-json-modules": true
}
```

```json
// test/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext"
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

Vite type definitions:

```js
// src/vite-env.d.ts
/// <reference types='vite/client' />

type MyCustomType= {
  start: string,
  end: string
};
```

Module to test:

```js
// src/ts/myModule.ts
function foo({ start, end }: MyCustomType): string {
   // ...
}

export { foo };
```

Test file:

```js
// test/unit/myModule.spec.ts
import 'mocha';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { foo } from '../../src/ts/myModule.js';

describe("foo is awesome", () => {
  it("works! :D", () => {
    const bar = foo({ start: "", end: ""});
    expect(bar).to.be.string;
  });
});
```

Current error:

```bash
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/ts/myModule.ts:2:30 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyCustomType'.

2 function foo({ start, end }: MyCustomType): string {

...
```

Add `MyCustomType` definition directly into `myModule.ts` it does works. However, I would need to do that for tens of files which, in multiple cases, consume the same type definitions.

Setting `"types": [ "src/vite-env.d.ts" ]` in `compilerOptions` is making no differences.

How can I make TS-Node to use type definitions from `vite-env.d.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["path/to/d.ts", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

to your tsconfig.json

And if I see it correctly, then the location of the tsconfig.json isn't correct
As I know the tsconfig.json should be on the root of the project like the package.json

Comment: Updated the question to say that I've already tried that. I'm starting to think that I'm not referencing the `tsconfig.json` file correctly, so it is actually being ignored/not used.

Comment: Actually, there is a `tsconfig.json` file in the root folder. I'm overriding it with the one inside the `test` folder as it is closer to the scripts transpiled by TS-Node (at least that's my intention).

Comment: Ok, I have a `tsconfig.json` in root folder and one in another folder, but the other `tsconfig.json` is only extending from the one in root

Maybe its because, the tsconfig cant see the d.ts because the path is like '../src/*.d.ts'

Answer (score 0):

```json
{
  "files": [
    "./vite-env.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
  
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding a small explanation on how / why this answer the question.